# Spring-Integration Partition for SQS

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, amazon-sqs

I'm trying setup spring-integration partitioning.

I'm use the stack spring-batch & integration & AWS SQS

1. Master - complete partition of grid size.
2. Master - transfer Object(StepExecutionRequest) to JSON 
            (@Transformer ObjectToJsonTransformer)
3. Master - send the SQS.
4. Slave - receive the SQS
5. Slave - transfer JSON to Object(StepExecutionRequest)
           (@Transformer JsonToObjectTransformer)

Then, the exception that occurs:

```
2018-06-22 17:40:55.578 ERROR 33730 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.StepExecutionRequest` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

That is `StepExecutionRequest` can not deserialize because the `StepExecutionReuqest` is not setter.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`StepExecutionRequest` is not suitable for serialization using JSON out of the box; as the error indicates, it has no default constructor. Use Java Serialization instead, or write a custom jackson `JsonDeserializer`.

Comment: Time to improve Spring Batch on the matter?

Comment: I've raised a JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2732

Comment: I solve to make the custom transfomer (JsonToStepExecutionRequestTransformer by JsonToObjectTransformer) Thank you @Gary Russell